# Minima of $x+y+\frac{1}{xy}$ given $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: inequality

> If $x,y$ are positive reals satisfying $x^2+y^2=1$, then the minimum value of $x+y+\frac{1}{xy}$ is?

##### Attempt 1

I used the Lagrange multipliers method which ended up being cumbersome.

##### Attempt 2

I applied the AM-GM inequality to obtain $\frac{1}{xy}\ge2$ and $x+y\le\sqrt2$ after which I'm lost again.

Im looking for hints/better approaches to the problem.

Comment: @Saad It does. I was pretty darn sure that this question would be present on this site, but I never found it when I was writing the post!

Comment: (In addition to that: since the expression is symmetric then $x=y$ gives either a local minimum or a local maximum. Since $x\to 0$ or $y\to0$ give maxima, it's 'sensible' that $x=y$ is a minimum; you should be able to prove it straightforwardly. Showing that the finction is increasing from $x=y$ to $x=0$ shouldn't be hard either.)

Comment: AM-GM the way you are applying will not work as $x, y$ can be negative

Comment: It has been mentioned in the question that they are positive reals @MathLover(though the linked question doesnt)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki noted

Comment: OK I see that now. Can you share how you approached using Lagrange Multiplier method? It should have given you point $x = y$ and minimum of $2 + \sqrt2$ which is also evident by symmetry.

Comment: @MathLover I did the usual things and ended up with an equation with squares and square roots(as a result of substitution of $y$)

Comment: You surely get $x = y$ as one of the points when you apply Lagrange Multiplier method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127434/discussion-between-datboi-and-math-lover).

Comment: @Saad the question that you have tagged this as a duplicate of does not state that $a, b$ are positive real. Even the accepted solution does not call out, which would be wrong without $a, b \gt 0$ constraint. There are comments asking OP if they had forgotten $a, b \gt 0$ constraint which OP never cares to respond to or edit the question.

Comment: How did lagrange multipliers turn out cumbersome????

Comment: @Buraian check out the discussion in the chat

Comment: I think I got the problem, the issue is that you have to use some algebra tricks to keep the calculations in Lagrange simple. Direct application is of lagrange can be dificult at times